# Support of GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT for cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage

Tags: opengl, cuda, depth-buffer

I'm trying to perform combined rendering with OpenGL for polygonal rendering and CUDA for volume rendering.  My idea is to render the OpenGL scene into a framebuffer, then use that color and depth buffer as input to my CUDA renderer, using it in the same way as OpenGL does, so I get proper alpha and depth compositing.

However, I'm running into a problem.  When I call:

```
glGenTextures(1, &m_tex_color);
glGenTextures(1, &m_tex_depth);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex_color);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_iWidth, m_iHeight, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex_depth);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, m_iWidth, m_iHeight, 0,  
             GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &m_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex_color, 0 );
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_tex_depth, 0 );
cudaError_t b;
b = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&m_cuda_color_resource, m_tex_color,
                                GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);
printf("%s",  cudaGetErrorString(b));
b = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&m_cuda_depth_resource, m_tex_depth,
                                GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);
printf("%s",  cudaGetErrorString(b));
```

I get no error on the first `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`, but an "invalid argument" error on the second.  Does CUDA 3.2 not support registering depth component textures?  Does 4.0 (when it comes out)?  Is there another way to approach this that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think there is depth support in CUDA 3.2 textures. CUDA 4.0 does introduce "layered textures", which I presume allows depth components, but I don't really use GL interop much with CUDA so that is just a guess.

Comment: I think the "layered textures" refers to multiple mipmap levels.

Comment: It definitely isn't mipmaps - those are not supported at all in CUDA yet.

Comment: The 4.0RC2 doc page for [cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0_rc2/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__INTEROP_g09f772ed8c6e8e03f396a8895fc42050.html#g09f772ed8c6e8e03f396a8895fc42050) talks about mipmap levels.  This doesn't really help me though, unfortunately.

Comment: layered textures doesn't relate to depth textures nor to mipmaps. layered textures are a form of 3D texture (a 2D texture with multiple layers). depth textures may indeed not be supported. you need to use RGBA8 texture and pack depth to color in shader (use multiple render targets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA GL texture interop does not currently support GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT (as of CUDA 4.1).

This was unfortunately overlooked in the CUDA documentation.  A documentation bug has been filed to rectify this.